Degree of Line Bundle Locally Constant in Flat Families
several times I encountered the statement "the degree of a line bundle is constant in flat families" in literature. I interpret this statement as:
Let $C \to S$ be a flat family of smooth projective curves and $\mathcal{L}$ a line bundle on $C$ with $S$ connected, then for all geometric points $s \to S$ the degree of the restriction of $\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathcal{L}_s$, so the pullback of $\mathcal{L}$ under the map $C_s \to C$, is the same.
However, I have the following example in mind, that concerns me: Let $R$ be a DVR with uniformiser $\pi$ and $f$ be the morphism $\mathbb{P}^1_R \to \mathbb{P}^1_R$ that is induced by the map $x \mapsto \pi x^2+x$. If we now consider the line bundle $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_R}(1)$, this line bundle has degree $2$ on the generic fibre as it is the pullback by a morphism of degree $2$, while on the special fibre the morphism is of degree $1$, as the highest term vanishes after quotening out the ideal $(\pi)$.
I would be very grateful for any comment that can help me resolving this seeming confusion in my mind.

Define the morphism rigorously first. What you describe doesn’t induce a morphism.

The current definition of $f$ defines it as a rational map only, and to pull back a line bundle you need a regular morphism.

Thank you for pointing out this mistake. Any way to extend this rational map to a finite map will also induce a morphism of degree $2$ on the special fiber.

This map does not extend, that's the point.
